# Se ejecutan los métodos varias veces durante los test

Tags: java, spring, junit, jar

Tengo un problema que me está comiendo la cabeza desde hace dos días...

Tengo una libreria propia para generar 3 archivos con 4 formatos según el caso, dicho jar por libre(ejecutando Test y métodos main) lo hace correctamente, me genera el archivo que le pido y ninguno mas

Los 4 formatos son:
**Positiva

PositivaCancelacion

Negativa

NegativaCancelacion**

ejecuto el test de Negativa, y me genera los 3 archivos de Negativa que necesito, lo mismo con las demas.

El problema viene cuando uso dicha librería en otra aplicación.
Solicito que me genere los archivos de Negativa, y me genera Todos los demas también.

Clase Test:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class CargaNegativaBatchTest {

  @Rule
  public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

  @Test
  public void generarPositivaBatchTest(){
    SingletonSpring.getGeneradorArchivosBatch().generarArchivoBatchPositiva();
    System.out.println(UtilsGen.ARCHIVO);

  }
}
```

Clase GeneradorArchivos

```
@Service("generadorArchivosBatchService")
public class GeneradorArchivosBatchServiceImpl implements IGeneradorArchivosService {

  ....

  @Autowired
  private BboPositivaService bboPositivaService;
  @Autowired
  private UtilesService utilesService;

  @Autowired
  private Environment enviroment;

  public void generarArchivoBatchPositiva() {
    GeneratorPositivaBatch generatorPositivaBatch = new GeneratorPositivaBatch(
     bboPositivaService, utilesService, enviroment
    );
    generatorPositivaBatch.procesar();
  }

....Los otros generadores son identicos cambiando el Generador....
}
```

Y esta es la clase que se encarga de generar el archivo (perteneciente al jar comentado anteriormente)

```
@Component
public class GeneratorPositivaBatch {
  @Autowired
  private static Environment enviroment;
  @Autowired
  private static BboPositivaService bboPositivaService;
  @Autowired
  private static UtilesService utilesService;
  private static String SEP;
  private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(GeneratorPositivaBatch.class);

  public GeneratorPositivaBatch(BboPositivaService bboPositivaServiceI, UtilesService utilesServiceI, Environment enviromentI) {
    LOG.info(".......start generator fichero positivo Batch ...");
    System.out.println("start generator fichero positivo Batch ...");
    if (bboPositivaService == null) {
      bboPositivaService = bboPositivaServiceI;
    }

    if (enviroment == null) {
      enviroment = enviromentI;
    }

    if (utilesService == null) {
      utilesService = utilesServiceI;
    }

    LOG.info("........fin execution..... ");
  }

  public static void procesar() {
    SEP = utilesService.getValue(Constantes.DELIMITADOR_CARGA_BATCH);
    String rootFile = utilesService.getValue(Constantes.RUTA_FICHEROS_CARGA_BATCH);
    File file = new File(rootFile);
    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.mkdirs();
      System.out.println("Se ha creado el directorio: " + rootFile);
    }

    int nSize = Integer.parseInt(enviroment.getProperty("positivaBatch.size"));
    String sufix = enviroment.getProperty("positivaBatch.sufix");
    String operador = enviroment.getProperty("positivaBatch.operator");
    String pathOutput = rootFile + "\\" + sufix + operador;
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat(enviroment.getProperty("positivaBatch.patternFile"));
    String formatoSuffix = formato.format(new Date());
    pathOutput = pathOutput + formatoSuffix + ".csv";

    try {
      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathOutput));
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileOutputStream);
      int nGen = 999999999;
      int maxTipMod = 3;

      for(int i = 0; i < nSize; ++i) {
        double rndTipMod = Math.random() % 10.0D * (double)maxTipMod + 1.0D;
        int tipoMod = (int)rndTipMod;
        String imeiSel = GenFieldHelpers.genImeiRnd();
        String imsiSel = GenFieldHelpers.genTipoImsi();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(imsiSel)) {
          imsiSel = "";
        }

        String msisdnSel = GenFieldHelpers.genSisdn();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(msisdnSel)) {
          msisdnSel = "";
        }

        LOG.info(imeiSel);
        String codTipoUsuario = GenFieldHelpers.genTipoUsuario();
        out.write(imeiSel + SEP + imsiSel + SEP + msisdnSel + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genNomPropietario() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genDireccion() + SEP + codTipoUsuario + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTipoDoc() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genNumDoc() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTelf() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genNomPropietario() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genDireccion() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTipoUsuario() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTipoDoc() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genNumDoc() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTelf() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTipoDoc() + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genNumDoc() + SEP + tipoMod + SEP + GenFieldHelpers.genTx());
        if (i++ < nSize) {
          out.write("\t\n");
        }
      }

      out.close();
      fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException var20) {
      LOG.error(var20.getMessage(), var20);
    }

    compressCSVFile(pathOutput);
    generateDonefile(pathOutput, nSize);
  }

  private static void compressCSVFile(String path) {
    try {
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
      GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path + ".gz"));
      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

      int bytes_read;
      while((bytes_read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
      }

      in.close();
      out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException var5) {
      var5.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException var6) {
      var6.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private static void generateDonefile(String path, int nCases) {
    String done = path.substring(0, path.length() - 4);
    UtilsGen.ARCHIVO = done;
    done = done + ".done";
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    try {
      fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(done));
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileOutputStream);
      out.write(nCases);
      out.close();
      fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException var5) {
      var5.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException var6) {
      var6.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Ese test, me ejecuta `GeneratorPositivaBatch.class` 4 veces cuando debería de ser solo una vez

EDIT 1:
Adjunto dependencias:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernateframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${com.oracle.ojdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${org.log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>generadorPruebas</groupId>
            <artifactId>generadorPruebas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <org.hibernateframework.version>5.2.13.Final</org.hibernateframework.version>
        <org.springframework.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <com.oracle.ojdbc.version>11.1.0.7.0</com.oracle.ojdbc.version>
        <org.log4j.version>1.2.17</org.log4j.version>
        <commons.dbcp.version>2.2.0</commons.dbcp.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.7.25</org.slf4j.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.6</commons.io.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

________________Fin Edit1___________________

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: prueba a mandar tu `GeneratorPositivaBatch generatorPositivaBatch = new GeneratorPositivaBatch` a autowired `@Autowired GeneratorPositivaBatch generatorPositivaBatch;`

Comment: @RuslanLópez muchas gracias, no sé a que fue debido si en principio debería ser igual, pero el autowired me lo corrigió. Muchas gracias, si quieres añadirlo como respuesta y la doy por solucionada ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamene la línea

```
GeneratorPositivaBatch generatorPositivaBatch = new GeneratorPositivaBatch(
 bboPositivaService, utilesService, enviroment
);
```

Se llamará varias veces, ya que la creación de tu `GeneratorPositivaBatch` no la estás delegando a Spring, y por lo tanto `generatorPositivaBatch` no es un Singleton ( es decir que hay una única instancia por toda la aplicación en todo momento ).

Para delegarle la creación Spring lo más sencillo es que lo pongas con las demás variables y con la anotación `@Autowired`.

```
@Service("generadorArchivosBatchService")
public class GeneradorArchivosBatchServiceImpl implements IGeneradorArchivosService {

  @Autowired
  private BboPositivaService bboPositivaService;
  @Autowired
  private UtilesService utilesService;

  @Autowired
  private Environment enviroment;

  @Autowired
  GeneratorPositivaBatch generatorPositivaBatch;

  public void generarArchivoBatchPositiva() {
  }
```

Mi teoría de por qué se te crea 4 veces es que se hace una por cada bean (bboPositivaService, utilesService, enviroment y generadorArchivosBatchServiceImpl)